# PowerShell get CSV and add column from data query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Have a CSV that has headers "SamName", "Email", "UPN"

Each record is how it shows in AD currently.

I am trying to add a 5th column with the ObjectGUID as follows:

```
$CsvFile = Import-Csv C:\test\file.csv
$CsvFile | ForEach-Object -Process { `
    $data1 = Get-ADUser -Identity $_."SamName" -Properties * | Select-Object ObjectGUID
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserGUID -Value $data1 -PassThru } `
    Export-CSV C:\test\file2.csv
```

When I open the CSV, the new column is called "UserGUID" as I had expected.

The GUID's that show are like this:

```
@{ObjectGUID=2e9dddec-f95d-4c67-a374-b102ce7e6f74}
```

Why don't they just show `2e9dddec-f95d-4c67-a374-b102ce7e6f74` in the column instead?

A second question, is why at the top of the Csv do I see `#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two guesses to answer your questions...

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ObjectGUID
```

and

```
Export-CSV C:\test\file2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

See `Get-Help` for various commands to see all the options.

Comment: Worked a charm! Thank you!